# javascript: if first 2 chars are //, replace it with /

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I think I may need a regex for this, but since I suck at regexs was hoping someone here could spare a minute to help me.

Basically I have a variable (lets name it: `zippy`)
and if `zippy`'s value is `//blah.html`
I want to delete one slash from there so it becomes `/blah.html`

(the 2 slashes will ALWAYS be in the first two characters, IF they exist at all)

How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
zippy = zippy.replace('//', '/');
```

Comment: If zippy is "blah//bla" you will replace it too, that should probably not happen, right?

Comment: @Nanne: As per OP **the 2 slashes will ALWAYS be in the first two characters, IF they exist at all**

Comment: I need the rest of the stuff that comes after the slash as well... for example it should give me /blah.html

Comment: I read that as "If there should be any slashes to be changed, they will be in the first 2 characters", but I agree you can read it like you did too. But as it's easily fixed with a `^`, why not add that?

Comment: And dont i need an if() condition before to check if there are 2 slashes in the string?

Comment: @Ryan no - that means, "replace all occurrences of '//' with '/'".  If there are none, there'll be no replacements.

Comment: So many good answers, am just going to award this to the answer that I am using and that was first, thanks go to everything and voted up! Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Regex would work, so would

```
zippy = (zippy.substr(0,2)=="//"  ? zippy.substr(1) : zippy);
```

Answer (score 2):

Can't be simplier:

```
zippy=zippy.replace('^/{2}','/');
```

Also +1 for variable names.

Answer (score 2):

```
if(zippy.substring(0,2) == '//')
{
zippy = '/' + zippy.substring(2);
}
```

I'm under the impression that `substring(from,to)` has from inclusive and to exclusive. But something to that effect. I don't know if javascript has a `startsWith` method.

Edit: Oh if the slashes will always be at the beginning than go with replace.

Answer (score 1):

```
var zippy = "//blah.html"
var zippy_fixed = zippy.replace(/^\/\//, "/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Another;

```
zippy = zippy.substr(1 + zippy.indexOf("//"));
```